# Multiple failed login attempts in Windows 7 Starter

Tags: windows-7, login

I just bought a new netbook today and upon initial setup I somehow managed to setup an unintended password for Windows. Then upon reboot I obviously wasn't able to login; however after multiple attempts (about 25+ times) I was finally able to crack my own mistyped password through various permutation guesses. So my question is, do such repeated failed login attempts have any negative repercussions on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is, do such repeated failed login attempts have any negative repercussions on Windows?

Your copy of Windows? No. Out of the box, your PC does not have an account lockout policy.

Comment: Yes, luckily I did not set a maximum attempt lockout threshold. So by default Windows does not do anything in response to multiple failed attempts?

Comment: No it will not. You can configure it for your local machine here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781491(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_1